# hector_quadrotor_demo process dies

Tags: gazebo, ros-kinetic, ubuntu, hector-localization, hector-quadrotor

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
so I'll make this as  specific as possible, beginning with how created my workspace in kinetic.

I  tried several methods, because i was asked to preferably use "catkin build" instead of catkin_make:
i created a folder in ~/kinetic_ws:

1. [catkin init](http://catkin-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quick_start.html#initializing-a-new-workspace)

   Catkin workspace `/home/carsten` is already initialized. No action taken.
   WARNING: Source space `/home/carsten/src` does not yet exist.
2. [wstool init](https://personalrobotics.ri.cmu.edu/software/development-environment) 
   Didn't work aswell, so I used
3. [catkin_make](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/create_a_workspace)
   which resulted in `echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH /home/carsten/kinetic_ws/src:/opt/ros/kinetic/share`

I then

- rm build devel -rf

so that I could compile using the catkin build command.

So now that i have my workspace "properly" set up, I downloaded the following
(meta?)packages into my /src folder:

- git clone
  https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_quadrotor.git
- git clone
  https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_localization.git

I had to download several tools:

- sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-hector-gazebo
- sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-gazebo-plugins ros-kinetic-gazebo-ros-control
- sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-hector-models

I couldn't build the package, I googled and found a solution using

- rm -rf ~/.catkin_tools

Afterwards, i was able to compile:

```
catkin build hector_quadrotor
-------------------------------------------------------------
Profile:                     default
Extending:             [env] /opt/ros/kinetic
Workspace:                   /home/carsten/kinetic_ws
-------------------------------------------------------------
Source Space:       [exists] /home/carsten/kinetic_ws/src
Log Space:         [missing] /home/carsten/kinetic_ws/logs
Build Space:        [exists] /home/carsten/kinetic_ws/build
Devel Space:        [exists] /home/carsten/kinetic_ws/devel
Install Space:      [unused] /home/carsten/kinetic_ws/install
DESTDIR:            [unused] None
-------------------------------------------------------------
Devel Space Layout:          linked
Install Space Layout:        None
-------------------------------------------------------------
Additional CMake Args:       None
Additional Make Args:        None
Additional catkin Make Args: None
Internal Make Job Server:    True
Cache Job Environments:      False
-------------------------------------------------------------
Whitelisted Packages:        None
Blacklisted Packages:        None
-------------------------------------------------------------
Workspace configuration appears valid.

NOTE: Forcing CMake to run for each package.
-------------------------------------------------------------
[build] Found '17' packages in 0.0 seconds.                                   
[build] Updating package table.                                               
Starting  >>> catkin_tools_prebuild                                           
Finished  <<< catkin_tools_prebuild                       [ 2.0 seconds ]     
Starting  >>> hector_quadrotor_description                                    
Starting  >>> hector_uav_msgs                                                 
Finished  <<< hector_quadrotor_description                [ 1.8 seconds ]     
Finished  <<< hector_uav_msgs                             [ 8.6 seconds ]     
Starting  >>> hector_quadrotor_interface                                      
Starting  >>> hector_quadrotor_model                                          
Finished  <<< hector_quadrotor_interface                  [ 5.1 seconds ]     
Starting  >>> hector_quadrotor_controllers                                    
Starting  >>> hector_quadrotor_teleop                                         
Finished  <<< hector_quadrotor_model                      [ 5.5 seconds ]     
Finished  <<< hector_quadrotor_controllers                [ 15.2 seconds ]    
Finished  <<< hector_quadrotor_teleop                     [ 17.4 seconds ]    
Starting  >>> hector_quadrotor                                                
Finished  <<< hector_quadrotor                            [ 2.1 seconds ]     
[build] Summary: All 8 packages succeeded!                                    
[build]   Ignored:   10 packages were skipped or are blacklisted.             
[build]   Warnings:  None.                                                    
[build]   Abandoned: None.                                                    
[build]   Failed:    None.                                                    
[build] Runtime: 35.6 seconds total.                                          
[build] Note: Workspace packages have changed, please re-source setup files to use them.
```

But I was wondering why 10 packages were skipped.
I then compiled the other package:

```
catkin build hector_localization
-------------------------------------------------------------
Profile:                     default
Extending:          [cached] /opt/ros/kinetic
Workspace:                   /home/carsten/kinetic_ws
-------------------------------------------------------------
Source Space:       [exists] /home/carsten/kinetic_ws/src
Log Space:          [exists] /home/carsten/kinetic_ws/logs
Build Space:        [exists] /home/carsten/kinetic_ws/build
Devel Space:        [exists] /home/carsten/kinetic_ws/devel
Install Space:      [unused] /home/carsten/kinetic_ws/install
DESTDIR:            [unused] None
-------------------------------------------------------------
Devel Space Layout:          linked
Install Space Layout:        None
-------------------------------------------------------------
Additional CMake Args:       None
Additional Make Args:        None
Additional catkin Make Args: None
Internal Make Job Server:    True
Cache Job Environments:      False
-------------------------------------------------------------
Whitelisted Packages:        None
Blacklisted Packages:        None
-------------------------------------------------------------
Workspace configuration appears valid.
-------------------------------------------------------------
[build] Found '17' packages in 0.0 seconds.                                   
[build] Updating package table.                                               
Starting  >>> hector_pose_estimation_core                                     
Starting  >>> message_to_tf                                                   
_______________________________________________________________________________
Errors     << hector_pose_estimation_core:cmake /home/carsten/kinetic_ws/logs/hector_pose_estimation_core/build.cmake.000.log
CMake Warning at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:76 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "geographic_msgs"
  with any of the following names:

    geographic_msgsConfig.cmake
    geographic_msgs-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "geographic_msgs" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
  set "geographic_msgs_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.
  If "geographic_msgs" provides a separate development package or SDK, be
  sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)


CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "geographic_msgs"
  with any of the following names:

    geographic_msgsConfig.cmake
    geographic_msgs-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "geographic_msgs" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
  set "geographic_msgs_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.
  If "geographic_msgs" provides a separate development package or SDK, be
  sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)


cd /home/carsten/kinetic_ws/build/hector_pose_estimation_core; catkin build --get-env hector_pose_estimation_core | catkin env -si  /usr/bin/cmake /home/carsten/kinetic_ws/src/hector_localization/hector_pose_estimation_core --no-warn-unused-cli -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/carsten/kinetic_ws/devel/.private/hector_pose_estimation_core -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/carsten/kinetic_ws/install; cd -
...............................................................................
Failed     << hector_pose_estimation_core:cmake          [ Exited with code 1 ]
Failed    <<< hector_pose_estimation_core                [ 1.7 seconds ]      
Abandoned <<< hector_pose_estimation                     [ Unrelated job failed ]
Finished  <<< message_to_tf                              [ 6.5 seconds ]      
[build] Summary: 1 of 3 packages succeeded.                                   
[build]   Ignored:   14 packages were skipped or are blacklisted.             
[build]   Warnings:  None.                                                    
[build]   Abandoned: 1 packages were abandoned.                               
[build]   Failed:    1 packages failed.                                       
[build] Runtime: 6.6 seconds total.                                           
[build] Note: Workspace packages have changed, please re-source setup files to use them.
    enter code here
```

Build failed, i resourced my setup.bash and wanted to check my workspace (?)

```
carsten@carsten-prokopp:~/kinetic_ws$ source devel/setup.bash
carsten@carsten-prokopp:~/kinetic_ws$ echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH

/home/carsten/kinetic_ws/src/hector_localization/hector_localization:/home/carsten/kinetic_ws/src/hector_localization/hector_pose_estimation_core:/home/carsten/kinetic_ws/src/hector_localization/hector_pose_estimation:/home/carsten/kinetic_ws/src/hector_quadrotor/hector_quadrotor:/home/carsten/kinetic_ws/src/hector_quadrotor/hector_quadrotor_description:/home/carsten/kinetic_ws/src/hector_quadrotor/hector_uav_msgs:/home/carsten/kinetic_ws/src/hector_quadrotor/hector_quadrotor_interface:/home/carsten/kinetic_ws/src/hector_quadrotor/hector_quadrotor_controllers:/home/carsten/kinetic_ws/src/hector_quadrotor/hector_quadrotor_model:/home/carsten/kinetic_ws/src/hector_quadrotor/hector_quadrotor_teleop:/home/carsten/kinetic_ws/src/hector_localization/message_to_tf:/opt/ros/kinetic/share
```

Which looked way different than i expected, and I dont really know how to understand the changes.
Anyways, i googled and found the issue, so I installed

- sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-geographic-msgs

I then could compile the hector_localization package without warning,
**but it skipped 14 packages**

```
[build] Found '17' packages in 0.0 seconds.                                   
[build] Package table is up to date.                                          
Starting  >>> hector_pose_estimation_core                                     
Starting  >>> message_to_tf                                                   
Finished  <<< message_to_tf                              [ 0.2 seconds ]      
Finished  <<< hector_pose_estimation_core                [ 53.7 seconds ]     
Starting  >>> hector_pose_estimation                                          
Finished  <<< hector_pose_estimation                     [ 15.1 seconds ]     
[build] Summary: All 3 packages succeeded!                                    
[build]   Ignored:   14 packages were skipped or are blacklisted.
```

So I was wondering why, I googled and tried

```
catkin build --dry-run
-------------------------------------------------------------
Profile:                     default
Extending:          [cached] /opt/ros/kinetic
Workspace:                   /home/carsten/kinetic_ws
-------------------------------------------------------------
Source Space:       [exists] /home/carsten/kinetic_ws/src
Log Space:          [exists] /home/carsten/kinetic_ws/logs
Build Space:        [exists] /home/carsten/kinetic_ws/build
Devel Space:        [exists] /home/carsten/kinetic_ws/devel
Install Space:      [unused] /home/carsten/kinetic_ws/install
DESTDIR:            [unused] None
-------------------------------------------------------------
Devel Space Layout:          linked
Install Space Layout:        None
-------------------------------------------------------------
Additional CMake Args:       None
Additional Make Args:        None
Additional catkin Make Args: None
Internal Make Job Server:    True
Cache Job Environments:      False
-------------------------------------------------------------
Whitelisted Packages:        None
Blacklisted Packages:        None
-------------------------------------------------------------
Workspace configuration appears valid.
-------------------------------------------------------------
[build] Found '17' packages in 0.0 seconds.                                   
Packages to be built:
- hector_localization                (metapackage)
- hector_pose_estimation_core        (catkin)
- hector_pose_estimation             (catkin)
- hector_quadrotor                   (catkin)
- hector_quadrotor_demo              (catkin)
- hector_quadrotor_description       (catkin)
- hector_uav_msgs                    (catkin)
- hector_quadrotor_interface         (catkin)
- hector_quadrotor_actions           (catkin)
- hector_quadrotor_controller_gazebo (catkin)
- hector_quadrotor_controllers       (catkin)
- hector_quadrotor_model             (catkin)
- hector_quadrotor_gazebo_plugins    (catkin)
- hector_quadrotor_gazebo            (catkin)
- hector_quadrotor_pose_estimation   (catkin)
- hector_quadrotor_teleop            (catkin)
- message_to_tf                      (catkin)
Total packages: 17
```

So I don't know why they were being skipped even though they shouldve been build..
I thought maybe they weren't linked properly.
Next step i took was:

```
catkin build 
-------------------------------------------------------------
Profile:                     default
Extending:          [cached] /opt/ros/kinetic
Workspace:                   /home/carsten/kinetic_ws
-------------------------------------------------------------
Source Space:       [exists] /home/carsten/kinetic_ws/src
Log Space:          [exists] /home/carsten/kinetic_ws/logs
Build Space:        [exists] /home/carsten/kinetic_ws/build
Devel Space:        [exists] /home/carsten/kinetic_ws/devel
Install Space:      [unused] /home/carsten/kinetic_ws/install
DESTDIR:            [unused] None
-------------------------------------------------------------
Devel Space Layout:          linked
Install Space Layout:        None
-------------------------------------------------------------
Additional CMake Args:       None
Additional Make Args:        None
Additional catkin Make Args: None
Internal Make Job Server:    True
Cache Job Environments:      False
-------------------------------------------------------------
Whitelisted Packages:        None
Blacklisted Packages:        None
-------------------------------------------------------------
Workspace configuration appears valid.
-------------------------------------------------------------
[build] Found '17' packages in 0.0 seconds.                                   
[build] Updating package table.                                               
Starting  >>> hector_pose_estimation_core                                     
Starting  >>> hector_quadrotor_description                                    
Starting  >>> hector_uav_msgs                                                 
Starting  >>> message_to_tf                                                   
Finished  <<< hector_quadrotor_description                      [ 0.1 seconds ]
Finished  <<< hector_pose_estimation_core                       [ 0.3 seconds ]
Finished  <<< message_to_tf                                     [ 0.2 seconds ]
Starting  >>> hector_pose_estimation                                          
Finished  <<< hector_uav_msgs                                   [ 1.2 seconds ]
Starting  >>> hector_quadrotor_interface                                      
Starting  >>> hector_quadrotor_model                                          
Finished  <<< hector_pose_estimation                            [ 0.2 seconds ]
Starting  >>> hector_quadrotor_pose_estimation                                
Finished  <<< hector_quadrotor_interface                        [ 0.2 seconds ]
Starting  >>> hector_quadrotor_actions                                        
Finished  <<< hector_quadrotor_model                            [ 0.2 seconds ]
Starting  >>> hector_quadrotor_controller_gazebo                              
Starting  >>> hector_quadrotor_controllers                                    
Finished  <<< hector_quadrotor_controllers                      [ 2.9 seconds ]
Finished  <<< hector_quadrotor_controller_gazebo                [ 16.8 seconds ]
Starting  >>> hector_quadrotor_teleop                                         
Finished  <<< hector_quadrotor_pose_estimation                  [ 20.2 seconds ]
Starting  >>> hector_quadrotor_gazebo_plugins                                 
Finished  <<< hector_quadrotor_teleop                           [ 4.5 seconds ]
Starting  >>> hector_quadrotor                                                
Finished  <<< hector_quadrotor                                  [ 0.3 seconds ]
Finished  <<< hector_quadrotor_actions                          [ 23.3 seconds ]
_______________________________________________________________________________
Warnings   << hector_quadrotor_gazebo_plugins:cmake /home/carsten/kinetic_ws/logs/hector_quadrotor_gazebo_plugins/build.cmake.000.log
CMake Warning at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:166 (message):
  catkin_package() DEPENDS on 'gazebo' but neither 'gazebo_INCLUDE_DIRS' nor
  'gazebo_LIBRARIES' is defined.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:102 (_catkin_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:47 (catkin_package)


cd /home/carsten/kinetic_ws/build/hector_quadrotor_gazebo_plugins; catkin build --get-env hector_quadrotor_gazebo_plugins | catkin env -si  /usr/bin/cmake /home/carsten/kinetic_ws/src/hector_quadrotor/hector_quadrotor_gazebo_plugins --no-warn-unused-cli -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/carsten/kinetic_ws/devel/.private/hector_quadrotor_gazebo_plugins -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/carsten/kinetic_ws/install; cd -
...............................................................................
Finished  <<< hector_quadrotor_gazebo_plugins                   [ 20.1 seconds ]
Starting  >>> hector_quadrotor_gazebo                                         
Finished  <<< hector_quadrotor_gazebo                           [ 2.7 seconds ]
Starting  >>> hector_quadrotor_demo                                           
Finished  <<< hector_quadrotor_demo                             [ 2.4 seconds ]
[build] Summary: All 16 packages succeeded!                                   
[build]   Ignored:   1 packages were skipped or are blacklisted.              
[build]   Warnings:  1 packages succeeded with warnings.                      
[build]   Abandoned: None.                                                    
[build]   Failed:    None.                                                    
[build] Runtime: 46.9 seconds total.                                          
[build] Note: Workspace packages have changed, please re-source setup files to use them.
```

So now I have 1 warning and 1 package skipped.
I resourced my setup.bash and launched the demo:

> This code block was moved to the following github gist:
> https://gist.github.com/answers-se-migration-openrobotics/4e215958341024aa4636f8b687b39814

I was happy cause it worked, after being away from the PC this message showed:

```
    [gazebo_gui-2] process has died [pid 8996, exit code 139, cmd /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/gazebo_ros/gzclient __name:=gazebo_gui __log:=/home/carsten/.ros/log/9efbb74e-2f64-11e8-ab10-14dae9f473b3/gazebo_gui-2.log].
log file: /home/carsten/.ros/log/9efbb74e-2f64-11e8-ab10-14dae9f473b3/gazebo_gui-2*.log
```

---

So now I try to launch the demo, It opens RViz & Gazebo,
showing the following code:

> This code block was moved to the following github gist:
> https://gist.github.com/answers-se-migration-openrobotics/0fb5f40123eff4a40100da5009b222db

And my Gazebo crashes.
I know this is alot, but i thought every information could help.
Can anyone help me to get this working?
Best regards

EDIT: Following Stefan Kohlbrecher's advice made it work.
Compiling with

```
catkin build -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
```

still gave me a warning but it now works.

```
Warnings   << hector_quadrotor_gazebo_plugins:cmake /home/carsten/hector_quad/logs/hector_quadrotor_gazebo_plugins/build.cmake.000.log
CMake Warning at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:166 (message):
  catkin_package() DEPENDS on 'gazebo' but neither 'gazebo_INCLUDE_DIRS' nor
  'gazebo_LIBRARIES' is defined.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:102 (_catkin_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:47 (catkin_package)
```

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/286882/hector_quadrotor_demo-process-dies/) by [cazimirpro](https://answers.ros.org/users/34371/cazimirpro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-03-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just tried myself, this is the short version of how I reproduced the setup.

Make sure all dependencies are there:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-hector-gazebo ros-kinetic-gazebo-plugins ros-kinetic-gazebo-ros-control ros-kinetic-hector-models ros-kinetic-geographic-msgs ros-kinetic-joy
```

Make sure there is no workspace setup sourced from your .bashrc file or so (e.g. `env | grep ROS` should give a empty response when executed in the terminal where you run the commands below). Then run:

```
cd~
mkdir hector_quad
cd hector_quad
source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash
catkin init
mkdir src
cd src
git clone https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_localization.git
git clone https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_quadrotor.git
cd ..
catkin build -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
source devel/setup.bash
roslaunch hector_quadrotor_demo outdoor_flight_gazebo.launch
```

This makes the outdoor demo run for me. The fact that the gazebo ui crashes suggests that we are probably looking at a graphics card related issue.

To test if the issue is related to gazebo itself, you can run it standalone (note you need to do `source devel/setup.bash` for every terminal if you haven't added it the `.bashrc` file):

```
roslaunch gazebo_ros empty_world.launch
```

If that also crashes, this is an issue between your computer (most likely graphics driver) and gazebo. If it works, you can spawn a quadrotor into the world:

```
roslaunch hector_quadrotor_gazebo spawn_quadrotor.launch
```

Note you can edit your original question or post comments to this answer, please do not post an answer in reply to this one yourself.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2018-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1